# File I/O Help instead of FileOpen

Tags: .net, vb.net

So I have been using FileOpen, FileGet, and FileClose normally in my .net app. However, I was told by a friend that I should be using IO instead as its faster, and is overall better. I have been looking through the docs and I am still a bit confused. Here is my original code for a file binder:

```
'Opens file1 by user choice and gets contents
FileOpen(1, TextBox1.Text, OpenMode.Binary, OpenAccess.Read, OpenShare.Default)
filein = Space(LOF(1))
FileGet(1, filein)
FileClose(1)

'Opens file2 and gets contents
FileOpen(1, Application.StartupPath & "\file2.exe", OpenMode.Binary, OpenAccess.Read, OpenShare.Default)
file2 = Space(LOF(1))
FileGet(1, file2)
FileClose(1)

'Opens final file that will contain both binded files
FileOpen(1, filename, OpenMode.Binary, OpenAccess.ReadWrite, OpenShare.Default)
FilePut(1, file2 & filesplit & filein)
FileClose(1)
```

I have tried to use IO.File.WriteAllBytes and IO.File.WriteAllText with no luck. How would I go about changing my code around to use IO? Thanks

Comment: You should ask your friend for some proof. The methods you use are just a thin layer of abstraction over `System.IO`, so I expect very little between the methods.

Comment: The biggest problem is that you are storing binary data in a string.  Strings get normalized in vb.net and that's going to destroy the data.  You'll need to switch to a byte array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is code that you can use to read the file into a byte array:

```
Dim aBytes As Byte() = Nothing

Using oStream As New FileStream(sFileName, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read)
    If oStream IsNot Nothing Then
        Dim wLen As Integer

        wLen = CInt(New FileInfo(PathName).Length)
        ReDim aBytes(wLen - 1)
        oStream.Read(aBytes, 0, wLen)
        oStream.Close()
    End If
End Using
```

to write the byte array to a file:

```
File.WriteAllBytes(sFileName, aBytes)
```